# Ajax search is not working in django

Tags: ajax, django

I am newbie to django as well as to ajax. I need to do ajax search so I perform this as follows:

**views.py**

```
def search_titles(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        search_text = request.POST['search_text']
    else:
        search_text = ''


    articles = Article.objects.filter(title__contains=search_text)
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['articles'] = articles


    return render_to_response('ajax_search.html',args)
```

**models.py**

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)  
    thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

**ajax_search.html**

```
{% if articles.count > 0 %}

{% for article in articles %}
    <li><a href="/articles/get/{{ article.id }}/" >{{article.title}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}

{% else %}

<li> None to show! </li>

{% endif %}
```

**articles.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block sidebar %}
<ul>
    <li><a href="/articles/all">  Articles</a> </li>
    <li><a href="/articles/create">Create Article</a></li>
</ul>

<h3>Search</h3>

{% csrf_token %}

<input type = "text" id="search" name = "search"/>
<ul id ="search-results">

</ul>

{% endblock%}
```

I also inlucded

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/home/bishnu/Documents/python/django-mike/django_test/templates',

    )

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home/bishnu/Documents/python/django-mike/django_test/static',
)
```

and all the templates are folder templates and static files at static folder and my js files are in static/js/ directory.

also 
**ajax.js**

```
$(function(){

    $('#search').keyup(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/articles/search/",
            data: { 
                'search_text' : $('#search').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
            success: searchSuccess,
            dataType: 'html'
        });

    });

});

function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    $('#search-results').html(data);
}
```

**base.html**

```
{% load static %}
<DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}My Base Template{% endblock %}</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/default.css" %}" >
    <script src="{% static "js/ajax.js" %}"> </script>
    <script src="{% static "js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js" %}"> </script>



</head>

<body>
    <div id = "page">

        <div id = "sidebar">
            {% block sidebar %}
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/articles/all/">Articles</a></li>
                <li><a href="/admin/">Admin</a></li>
            </ul>
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}

            <img src="{% static "images/python_logo.jpg" %}" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But the ajax is not working, what is the problem here ?

Comment: Do you mind actually showing some AJAX code?

Comment: I edited my question adding ajax.js, Can you see it ?

Comment: What isn't working, specifically? Have you debugged at all? Also, where is your HTML form? Can you post it?

Comment: yes i tried to debug it and when I type on search bar i am expecting that it shows the results related to words typed on the search box but when i type some text on search box, nothing happens.

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console? If you are using Chrome, press Ctrl+Shift+i to open the Developer Tools, and select the console tab. You can also check the network tab to see if the ajax request was sent and what the response was (open the network tab first, then trigger the ajax request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example from Mike Hibbert's django tut. I think your css/js is not loaded because you are loading it up as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/default.css" %}" >
<script src="{% static "js/ajax.js" %}"> </script>
<script src="{% static "js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js" %}"> </script>
```

while his video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKSNciGr8kY mentions that you should have it as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "assets/css/default.css" %}" >
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/ajax.js' %}"></script>
```

I don't know what your staticfiles config is. But follow the instructions present in the video one more time and I think it should work as it had worked for me.